# Flashgot alternative for Firefox quantum

Tags: gratis, firefox, download-manager

Flashgot doesn't work with quantum anymore, I want a similar extension which would work with uGet on Linux.

Basically an extension that would let me click on a download link and open it with uGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded this

https://slgobinath.github.io/uget-chrome-wrapper/

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper/master/build/linux/install_uget_chrome_wrapper.sh

sudo sh install_uget_chrome_wrapper.sh
```

Then [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ugetintegration/), and it worked, for now there's no other option.